# How to use Supabase streams to query "IS NOT NULL" where clause

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

How do I make the following query in supabase on a stream listening for changes:

```sql
select * from public.messages where "to" IS NOT NULL;
```

From the documentation the closest, I could get was doing the filtering with an "equal to" expression. As captured below:

```dart
_messagesStream = supabase
        .from('messages:to=eq.123')
        .stream(['id'])
        .order('created_at')
        .execute()
        .map((maps) => maps
            .map((map) => Message.fromMap(map: map, myUserId: myUserId))
            .toList());
```

But what I need is a query with "IS NOT NULL". A work around I found was to handle complex queries in a view, but the issue here is, I cannot listen for events on view.

Kindly assist.

Comment: As @igdmitrov has answered, there is no `is not` filter in `stream()` method as there is no such methods in Supabase realtime at the moment. `stream()` uses Supabase realtime engine under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible.
I checked supabase.dart and I can't find any solution on how to implement it.

But you can filter it on your side:

```
 _messagesStream = supabase
        .from('messages:to=eq.123')
        .stream(['id'])
        .order('created_at')
        .execute()
        .map((maps) => maps
           .where((element) => element['to'] != null)
            .map((map) => Message.fromMap(map: map, myUserId: myUserId))
            .toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

From Supabase docs / Filters / is()

```
    const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('countries')
    .select()
    .is('name', null)
```

Comment: The question is about "not" null.

Comment: The question is also about a stream, not the basic select

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from('table')
        .select('*') 
        .not('column', 'is', null)
```